# Spanish Character ó getting broken from regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a script that needs to scan through words in a block of text. Part of it includes cleaning up the text to being just plain words with no added punctuation except apostrophes for compound words, however the encoding on one particular Spanish character seems to break every time I put it through this line:

```
$content = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z'’`ÀàÂâÆæÈèÉéÊêËëÎîÏïÔôŒœÙùÛûÜüŸÿüáÁéÉíÍñÑóÓúÚüÜ¿¡«»]/iu", " ", $content);
```

The character in question is the `ó`. In this case I'm testing the word liquidación and it comes back as `liquidaciÃ³n` when I print out the result.

Is there a way to fix this, or a better way to clean up a block of text while leaving English, French, and Spanish characters alone?

Comment: This has nothing to do with regex, it's because you display the result in your browser without adding `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` to define the correct encoding in the head of your html.

Comment: I've tried adding this but it's still not reading out correctly. I've also tried printing it to a text file and opening it in Notepad++ set to UTF-8 encoding and the character shows as "xC3" surrounded by a black box.

Comment: That depends on the charset used in your php installation and the charset of the caracters incoming to the php script, and also the charset of the characters you use to specify your regexp.